# Pyspark alpabet index

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I need to assign my letters alphabetically.
For instance:
Moreover, the letters are of type list.
I have list 'simbol_combinations'

```
[Column<b'A'>, Column<b'B'>, Column<b'C'>, Column<b'D'>, Column<b'E'>, Column<b'F'>, Column<b'G'>, Column<b'H'>, Column<b'I'>, Column<b'J'>, Column<b'K'>, Column<b'L'>, Column<b'M'>, Column<b'N'>, Column<b'O'>, Column<b'P'>, Column<b'Q'>, Column<b'R'>, Column<b'S'>, Column<b'T'>, Column<b'U'>, Column<b'V'>, Column<b'W'>, Column<b'X'>, Column<b'Y'>, Column<b'Z'>]
```

And i have DataFrame 'unque_activity'

```
+--------------+
|activity_start|
+--------------+
|       Stage_3|
|       Stage_5|
|       Stage_4|
|       Stage_1|
|       Stage_6|
|       Stage_2|
|       Stage_0|
|       Stage_8|
|       Stage_7|
|       Stage_9|
+--------------+
```

unque_activity = df.select("activity_start").distinct()

I want this. Union DataFrame 'unque_activity' and list 'simbol_combinations'. How?

I want

```
    stages symbol
0  Stage_0      A
1  Stage_3      B
2  Stage_5      C
3  Stage_2      D
4  Stage_7      E
5  Stage_4      F
6  Stage_8      G
7  Stage_9      H
8  Stage_1      I
9  Stage_6      J
```

How? Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark, this is how I would solve this:

- Create DataFrame for both list
- Sort them
- Add row_num
- Join both dataframe on row_num

  ```
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
   from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
   from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,lit
   from pyspark.sql.window import Window

   spark = SparkSession.builder \
       .appName("Dyn") \
       .getOrCreate()

   activity_start = [
       "Stage_3", "Stage_5", "Stage_4", "Stage_1", "Stage_6", "Stage_2", "Stage_0", "Stage_8", "Stage_7",
       "Stage_9"]

   activity_name = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]

   w = Window().orderBy(lit('A'))
   activity_start_df = spark.createDataFrame(activity_start, StringType())
   activity_start_df = (
       activity_start_df
       .withColumnRenamed("value", "activity_start")
       .orderBy("activity_start")
       .withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(w))
   )

   activity_name_df = spark.createDataFrame(activity_name, StringType())
   activity_name_df = (
       activity_name_df
       .withColumnRenamed("value", "activity_name")
       .orderBy("activity_name")
       .withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(w))
   )

   df = (
       activity_start_df
       .join(
           activity_name_df,
           activity_start_df["row_num"] == activity_name_df["row_num"]
       )
   )
   df.show(truncate=False)
  ```

Output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7iwo.png

Let me know if this helps.